# Android: res XML validation does not work in IntelliJ 12

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ development and am using the Android plugins for my development.

However, I cannot get the XML validation or the auto-completion to work correctly.

The following is a snippet of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/competitionName"
            />
```

The validation tells me that all the android attributes are invalid. Likewise if I enter a new attribute it does not give me any suggestions.

I've had a look around the settings but I don't see what I am missing.

Can anyone help here?

Thanks